# finish vs have finished

Tags: grammar, tenses

It would be great if you help me!!

' if I have a class, then I'll usually make my way to lecture hall after I (finish / have finished ) eating. '

what's the right word between the two?
could you explain about the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at an analysis of the phrases' [usage in English literature](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=after%20i%20have%20finished.%2C%20after%20i%20finish.%2C%20after%20finishing.&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cafter%20I%20have%20finished%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20I%20finish%20.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20finishing%20.%3B%2Cc0).

As it turns out, as a sentence-final phrase (to eliminate unforeseen ambiguities), **'after I finish' is slightly more popular than 'after I have finished.'**

'After finishing' is also a popular construction, but cannot be compared honestly due to the lack of a subject ('I').

**Neither is incorrect.** Either is acceptable.

The meaning, also, is nearly identical. They are different grammatical forms but can be used interchangeably. Once you 'finish' something, you simultaneously achieve the state of 'having finished' that something. The timing of the two conditions is the same.

'I have finished' is **present perfect tense**. It describes your condition at any point in time after finishing. 'I finish' is **present simple tense** - describing your intended activity some time before finishing.

Your example also includes the preposition 'after,' so you're discussing any point in time after the condition has been satisfied; the condition for each is the same - finishing.